# Running unit test only for my custom module

Tags: 8, testing

Is there any way I can run unit testing only for my modules? I know there is a way to run a specific unit test but I want to run unit test for all tests under certain directory (/modules/custom in my case). Is it even possible? I want to do it so that CI/CD automatically runs unit tests only for my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is provide a path/file to phpunit and it will be limited to that.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c core modules/custom
```

Comment: tired this but running into an issue: `Declaration of Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase::assertEquals($expected, $actual, $message = '', $delta = 0, $maxDepth = 10, $canonicalize = false, $ignoreCase = false) must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertEquals($expected, $actual, string $message = '', float $delta = 0, int $maxDepth = 10, bool $canonicalize = false, bool $ignoreCase = false): void in /var/www/drupal/web/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php on line 44` any idea what that is? I am guessing some versions issues (durpal 8.5.3).

Comment: was versions issue. I had to downgrade phpunit to 4.8.36 on php 7.1 and d 8.5.3